# Ошибка при запуске Python файла со ссылкой на .kv файл

Tags: python, kivy

Это содержание файла киви:

```
 # File name: hello2.kv
 #: kivy 1.9.0
 <Label>:
        text: "Hello world!"
```

Это питон:

```
import kivy
kivy.require ('1.9.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label

class Hello2App(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Hello2App().run()
```

А вот результат.
[image: Результат ошибка]

В чем проблема, помогите, пожалуйста? Что не работает?

Comment: почему у вас версии `kivy` разные в коде и при запуске?

Comment: Пишу по учебнику, устанавливал позже )

Comment: попробуйте в PyCharm проект запустить, там зависимости и ошибки проще распознаются, ваш код вполне рабочий, видимо проблема при установке какой то зависимости

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй поместить kv файл в папку с пайтон файлом и написать.

```
import kivy
kivy.require ('1.9.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

Builder.load_file('hello2.kv')
class Hello2App(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Hello2App().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле эта ошибка возникает из-за того, kivy logger не может вывести лог в файл, в следствии того что не умеет правильно интерпретировать пути содержащие кириллические символы (что собственно и написано у вас в логе). Лог выводится в домашнюю папку .kivy, по умолчанию путь которой в windows vista и выше определяется как `"c:\Users\USER_NAME\.kivy\"`. Т.е. причина кроется в том, что у вас имя пользователя windows написано с содержанием кириллических символов (русские буквы т.е.). Есть несколько способов что можно с этим сделать:

- самый логичный, это конечно же никогда не называть пользователя в русской раскладке, потому как и в других программа встречаются подобные проблемы.
- самый хакерский и грязный, это пропатчить файл `__init__.py` в корневом каталоге библиотеки kivy, изменив `kivy_home_dir` в строке `kivy_home_dir = join(user_home_dir, '.kivy')` на нужный путь. Но при обновлении, все вернется "на круги своя", да и вообще по рукам за такое бить надо Х)
- самый легкий, создать новую переменную среды KIVY_HOME в которой прописать другой путь для папки .kivy, который не будет содержать кириллических символов.
- самый правильный и трудный, это конечно же исправить этот баг в kivy, так что бы logger.py корректно декодировались все символы и отправить pull request в мастер ветку Kivy на github :)

Answer (score 0):

У вас Python 2.7 - попробуйте изменить это:

```
        text: u"Hello world!"
```